# Change site links on our Stack Exchange profile pages to use actual site names, not domains

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, user-accounts, stackexchange.com

If you visit [your own Stack Exchange network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current), you can scroll down a bit to see your Top Questions and Top Answers. Each of those link to the site the question/answer comes from on the right hand side.

I'd like to suggest these links should use the site title, instead of the domain name. Currently it says e.g. [image: "stackoverflow.com"] for a question that comes from Stack Overflow, but I suggest it should say [image: "Stack Overflow"] instead. It looks more appropriate.

Comment: Where do you find these links at their network account page?

Comment: @Luuklag, after appending *?tab=top* to *stackexchange.com/users/[ID]/[NAME]*, they are on the right of each top post. You can also just switch to the "Top" tab.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS Even after your comment I can't make out what you are talking about.

Comment: I suppose I found a page like you are talking about via my meta.se profile page top posts list, but the ID there is not my meta.se ID.

Comment: @philipxy I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: I`m saying your post is not clear & your comment is neither clear nor correct & to clarify posts via edits not comments. Please edit your post to clearly identify the page & problem.

Comment: I've done some digging into what this feature request might be referring to, and redrafted it for clarity. @IAmAStudent My changes were pretty much a rewrite, please review them and update further as you'd like.

Comment: @doppelgreener Thanks. To see those links one has to select the 'top' tab on that profile page & one has to have posted an answer or question.

Comment: I don't think this feature request is likely to be implemented. This page is pretty outdated and will probably eventually be replaced with a new design using stacks, their frontend framework.